# AdMob native ads in React Native

Tags: react-native, admob, native-ads

What options does react native have for native ads (ios and android)? I try rnfirebase admob and there are InterstitialAd, RewardedAd, BannerAd. I need ads that appear within the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rnfirebase`: BannerAd is the only option that could be shown within content for now.

You can use this as well [react-native-admob-native-ads](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-admob-native-ads)

Comment: Can I put id of native ad (ad unit) in rnfirebase BannerAd  and and put it in the middle and at the end of content?  Whether it is the correct way?

Comment: Yes, you can add id ```<BannerAd unitId={TestIds.BANNER}```, and specify size as you want from here : https://rnfirebase.io/reference/admob/banneradsize. but I think react-native-admob-native-ads is the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Admob is removed from firebase(Google Firebase team have removed it in upstream level) and It will never be in react-native-firebase again. So give a try with [react-native-admob](https://github.com/izetmolla/react-native-admob-next).